# Obtaining the value the last value in a series to match certain criteria in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with raw data, including pertinent data shown below, which is ordered by timestamp.

df1

```
   Line   Timestamp  Depot  Product
0  Line1    08:00       1     P1
1  Line1    08:10       1     P1
2  Line2    08:15       1     P4
3  Line1    08:20       1     P1
4  Line3    08:23       2     P13
5  Line1    08:30       2     P1
```

I have a summary tables for each production line derived from this, with pertinent data as shown below:

df2

```
   Line   Product  Depot  Time_Complete
0  Line 1   P1       1      NaN
1  Line 1   P1       2      NaN
2  Line 1   P2       1      NaN
3  Line 1   P2       1      NaN
```

What I'm trying to do is take the last timestamp from the first dataframe matching particular criteria.  In this case if Line 1, P1, Depot 1 has the last time stamp would be 08:20.  I'm not 100% sure where to start with this type of wrangling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by specified columns and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df11 = df1.drop_duplicates(['Line','Depot','Product'], keep='last')
df = df2.merge(df11, on=['Line','Depot','Product'], how='left')
print (df)
    Line Product  Depot  Time_Complete Datestamp
0  Line1      P1      1            NaN     08:20
1  Line1      P1      2            NaN     08:30
2  Line1      P2      1            NaN       NaN
3  Line1      P2      1            NaN       NaN
```

Comment: Perfect jezrael, I had all merge values as NaN initially but down to incompatible dtypes on the 'merge on' columns, once they matched it works as desired.  Thanks